# Inconsistent MFC Flickering even when using bitblt

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, bitblt

I'm experiencing flicker when rotating a rectangle but not when moving a rectangle, even though I'm using the same show function. It is a floor layout scenario.

Some images to illustrate. The red rectangle in the centre is selected and moved:

[image: Move example]

But when trying to rotate the following happens:

[image: Rotate example]

The code used to rotate a rectangle:

```
m_pDrawRect->SetRelativeAngle(point, m_pntLast, RECT_SELECTED | RECT_RECURSIVE);
m_pDrawRect->SetRelativePosition(point, m_pntLast, RECT_SELECTED |RECT_RECURSIVE);
CRecordDC dcRecord(m_pMemDC->GetDC(this, TRUE));
m_pDrawRect->Draw(&dcRecord, RECT_SELECTED);
m_pMemDC->Show(this);
```

The show function:

```
Show(CWnd *pWnd)
{
CDC *pMainWnd=pWnd->GetDC();
pMainWnd->BitBlt(rcPaint.left, rcPaint.top, rcPaint.Width(), rcPaint.Height(), m_pMemDC, rcPaint.left, rcPaint.top, SRCCOPY);
pWnd->ReleaseDC(pMainWnd);
```

Comment: You ought to show an SSCCE. But it looks very much like you are not painting at the right point in the code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank you for the response. It's difficult to give an example because it is part of a much larger application. Where would you suggest I draw?

Comment: I would suggest that you bite the bullet and make a short SSCCE. For sure you cannot post your entire project but surely you can make a <100 line SSCCE to demonstrate the project. As for where to paint, well in response to `WM_PAINT` of course, or however that surfaces in MFC.

Comment: Yes, `Show()` should just invalidate the rectangle, you need to do the painting logic in the [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01c9aaty.aspx) handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by replacing the show function with:

```
CRect rcPaint;
this->GetClientRect(rcPaint);
CDC *pDCOld = m_pMemDC->GetDC(this, TRUE);
CDC pDCTemp;
pDCTemp.CreateCompatibleDC(pDCOld);
CMemDC memDC(pDCTemp, rcPaint);
CDC* pDC = &memDC.GetDC();
pDC->BitBlt(rcPaint.left, rcPaint.top, rcPaint.Width(), rcPaint.Height(), pDCOld,
rcPaint.left, rcPaint.top, SRCCOPY);
Invalidate();
```

The object this refers to the current CView object. This works but it's slightly unresponsive.